# Sed command strange thing

Tags: regex, sed

Can someone please explain to me what this command does?

```
sed 's/\|/replacement/g' somefile
```

I can't understand WHY at any char he puts the replacement.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: If you want to replace `|` don't escape it.

Comment: I don't want to replace |, i was try some commands and this one gave to me and unexpecter reslut, example: if somefile is: blablabla And sed 's/\|/ /g' somefile the result will be b l a b l a b l a b l a. And only with the string \| apears this. Why not with \¥ or \♤ or \Q?

Comment: Because `\|` means "or". Your code is equivalent to `s//replacement/g`; you're replacing the empty string (which exists between all characters) by `replacement`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax

Comment: `s//replacement/g` shows with GNU sed: `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Comment: s//replacement/g does not work and also .|. has a different behavior

Comment: This .\|. Is equal to write just a point. It's telling substitute any character OR any character with "replacement", I'm not tring to do anytingh, i was just writing some code and misspelled something and got that result and just wanted to know why.

Comment: They do NOT behave in the same way. I'm testing it right now at the pc

Comment: I can also see this like a new question: How can I insert at any position a specified character with sed, the answer is sed '/\|/.....' but i would not be able to answer at this question if I did not taped this command by mistake

Answer (score 2):

Which version of `sed` are you using on which platform?  Some versions of `sed` (such as GNU [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)) treat `\|` as activating an 'or' condition, in which case, you are matching an empty string or an empty string, which matches at all points in the input (between each character), giving you the claimed result.

Other versions of `sed` (such as BSD `sed`, also found on macOS Sierra, etc) follow the POSIX standard for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) more closely and do not make `\|` into an 'or' condition.

If you add `-E` or `-r` to enable 'extended regular expressions', then `\|` becomes a literal pipe.  If you want to match pipe symbols, you don't need to (shouldn't need to) do anything special.  By default, `sed` uses a slightly extended version of POSIX's Basic Regular Expressions or BRE.

#### tester.sh

Using the `-e` option is unnecessary but I do it because it is also unambiguous; using the `-n` option avoids repeated output; using the `l` command lists the output unambiguously — `sed` adds a `$` at the end of the line of output; using quotes around `"$rx"` is crucial; using quotes around `"$sed"` is good but not necessary for the paths used; and using no quotes around `$opt` is also crucial as it ensures no option is present when the string is empty, but expands safely to `-E` on the other iteration.

```
for sed in /usr/bin/sed /opt/gnu/bin/sed
do
    for rx in 's/|/ /g;l' 's/\|/ /g;l' 
    do
        for opt in '' '-E'
        do
            (set -x; echo "blablabla|gibberish" | "$sed" $opt -n -e "$rx")
        done
    done
done
```

#### Output

```
$ bash tester.sh
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /usr/bin/sed -n -e 's/|/ /g;l'
blablabla gibberish$
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /usr/bin/sed -E -n -e 's/|/ /g;l'
sed: 1: "s/|/ /g;l
": RE error: empty (sub)expression
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /usr/bin/sed -n -e 's/\|/ /g;l'
blablabla gibberish$
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /usr/bin/sed -E -n -e 's/\|/ /g;l'
blablabla gibberish$
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -n -e 's/|/ /g;l'
blablabla gibberish$
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -E -n -e 's/|/ /g;l'
 b l a b l a b l a | g i b b e r i s h $
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -n -e 's/\|/ /g;l'
 b l a b l a b l a | g i b b e r i s h $
+ echo 'blablabla|gibberish'
+ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -E -n -e 's/\|/ /g;l'
blablabla gibberish$
$
```

On my machine, `/usr/bin/sed` is the BSD `sed` while (surprise) `/opt/gnu/bun/sed` is GNU `sed`.  The BSD version doesn't like the two empty patterns with `sed -E -n -e 's/|/ /g;l'`.